# Does Yerba Mate contain Beta carbolines like harman and norharman?

Tags: botany, pharmacology

I know that this is true of (roasted) coffee but haven't been able to find any reliable information about mate in its smoked or steamed state.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of research I can say that Yerba mate does not contain beta-carbolines. Now, I don't know if this makes you happy or sad but the tea has many antioxidant properties which makes it good for health. You can find a list of the components in Yerba mate in [paper 1](http://www.scielo.cl/pdf/chiljar/v72n2/at16.pdf) and [this article](http://www.yerba-mate.com/content/yerbamate.pdf).

Comment: Hi. I'm the OP.  I just wanted to thank you for your answer.